# Deploy jruby project to tomcat in windows platform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby, warbler

I am newbie in the ruby world, after doing some research I can generate a demo rails application and testing on the webrick server

But I have encounter the problem when I start to deploy with tomcat
I use warbler to generate war file for deployment successfully without error
Copy the war under the folder of webapps on Tomcat 7.0
start the server and try to run on the browser
I found that assets file is not accessible & the controller method cannot redirect to correct view, but display "We're sorry, but something went wrong." message

Config of the deployment I have try

```
JRuby 1.7.0
Gems    
    jruby-rack 1.1.10, 1.0.10
    rails 3.2.9, 3.2.0
    warbler 1.3.6, 1.3.2
Tomcat 7.0.32
```

here is the access log from tomcat

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2012:13:56:38 +0800] "GET /demo/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5906
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2012:13:56:49 +0800] "GET /demo/assets/rails.png HTTP/1.1" 404 728
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2012:14:01:21 +0800] "GET /demo/order/add HTTP/1.1" 500 643
```

here is the log form tomcat

```
    2012/11/20 13:56:18 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

    INFO: jruby 1.7.0 (1.9.3p203) 2012-10-22 ff1ebbe on Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_34-b04 [Windows XP-x86]

    2012/11/20 13:56:18 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

    INFO: using : runtime pool with acquire timeout of 10.0 seconds

    2012/11/20 13:56:19 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

    ContextListener: contextInitialized()

    2012/11/20 13:56:19 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

    SessionListener: contextInitialized()

    2012/11/20 13:56:19 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

    ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@1858aa0')

    2012/11/20 01:56:38 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

    INFO: pool was empty - getting new application instance

    2012/11/20 01:56:47 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

    Started GET "/demo/assets/rails.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-20 13:56:47 +0800


    2012/11/20 01:56:47 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

    Connecting to database specified by database.yml


    2012/11/20 01:56:49 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log


    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/rails.png"):
    gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
    gems/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
    gems/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
    gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
    gems/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
    gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
    gems/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
    gems/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
    gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
    gems/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
    gems/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
    gems/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
    gems/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
    gems/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
    gems/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
    gems/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
    gems/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
    file:/lib/jruby-rack-1.1.10.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'




    2012/11/20 14:01:21 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

    Started GET "/demo/order/add" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-20 14:01:21 +0800


    2012/11/20 14:01:21 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

    Processing by OrderController#add as HTML


    2012/11/20 14:01:21 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

    Rendered order/add.html.erb within layouts/application (16.0ms)


    2012/11/20 14:01:21 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log

    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 78ms
```

It's seem that the routing problem is occur, is it the problem when I deploy the rails application other than the ROOT location?

I have research the similar topic of this, I have try some solution, such as
adding the below command at production.rb, but no help.

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/demo"
```

Thanks for your solutions

Comment: +1 ...I had precompiled my assets, but needed to set config.action_controller.relative_url_root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you precompile your assets before warbling?

You need to run `rake assets:precompile` to generate static content before running `warble`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Is that I need to run the command everytime once the asset folder has been changed?

Comment: Yeah, kinda troublesome. Compiling assets takes long very time. For dev we usually run `rails server` locally. We compile assets & warble only for QA & PROD servers. And it's done by our CI.

Comment: one more important thing: if you compile the assets in your local dev folder and  run `rails server` it will be picking up your asset twice. From app/assets and public/assets. You need to clean up compliled assets before running `rails server`. `rake assets:clean` should do the job

Comment: Thanks once again, your advise is precious

Comment: @arkadiy +1 for > rake assets:clean